# Breaking object deadlock

Tags: java, multithreading, oop, object, deadlock

Good evening! Dears, I apologize in advance for the bad text. English is not my native language. The problem is this: there is code and I even sort of figured out how the deadlock is implemented. But there is a problem how to get out of it.
I was told to either synchronize the capture or invoke the threads sequentially.

I tried as follows:

- I delete monitors from methods and created a static object in the class and threw it into the monitor, and if you call the threads, it will work, but if you call the threads into a loop, everything collapses.
- I also tried to rewrite the function so bower.bowBack (this) to this.bowBack (bower) so that 2 objects are not called from 1 thread, but it is still worth putting it into the loop and again we don’t have what we need.

Tell me please how you can solve the problem?

Update: I apologize for not being informative. I will improve.
According to the assignment, you need 2 streams to be output:

- A: G shot me
- A: I shoot back
- G: And he shot me

(stream 1)

- G: And he shot me
- G: I shoot back
- A: G shot me.

(stream 2)

And he does just that. But as soon as you put it into the cycle, it freezes. How to organize sequential work of threads? I don't understand how to implement it correctly.

```
package pr1;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.Lock;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock;

//package ru.philosophyit;



public class DeadLock {

  static class Friend {
    private final String name;
    
    private final Lock lock = new ReentrantLock();
    
    public Friend(String name) {
      this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName() {
      return name;
    }
    
    public void bow(Friend bower) {
        
        boolean Lock_my = false;
        boolean Lock_bower = false;
        
        try
              {
                
                 while(!Lock_my || !Lock_bower)
                 {
                    Lock_my = this.lock.tryLock(100, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
                    Lock_bower = bower.lock.tryLock(100, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);

                 }
    
                 System.out.format("%s: %s подстрелил меня!\n", this.name, bower.getName());
                 System.out.format("%s: стреляю в ответ!\n", this.name);
                         
                 bower.bowBack(this);
    
                 this.lock.unlock();
                 bower.lock.unlock();
                }
        catch(InterruptedException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
             
    public void bowBack(Friend bower) {
     
        System.out.format("%s: %s подстрелил меня!\n", this.name, bower.getName());
    }
  }
  

  /**
   * Точка входа в программу
   
*
   * @param args аргументы командной строки
   */
  
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Friend alphonse = new Friend("Alphonse");
    Friend gaston = new Friend("Gaston");
    
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
    new Thread(() -> alphonse.bow(gaston)).start();
           
    new Thread(() -> gaston.bow(alphonse)).start();
    }
  }
    
}
```

I also did synchronization on a static object and the loop worked, but the output is not sequential. ie instead of 1 stream and then 2 there can be 1 stream 1 stream 2 stream 2 stream 1 stream. I can't figure out why.

```
package pr1;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.Lock;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock;

//package ru.philosophyit;



public class DeadLock {

  static Object o = new Object();
    
  static class Friend {
    private final String name;
    
    
    public Friend(String name) {
      this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName() {
      return name;
    }
    
    public void bow(Friend bower) {
        
        //synchronized(getClass())
        synchronized(o)
        {   
                 System.out.format("%s: %s подстрелил меня!\n", this.name, bower.getName());
                 System.out.format("%s: стреляю в ответ!\n", this.name);
                         
                 bower.bowBack(this);
    }
    }
             
    public void bowBack(Friend bower) 
    {
        //synchronized(getClass())
        synchronized(o)
        {
        System.out.format("%s: %s подстрелил меня!\n", this.name, bower.getName());
    }
    }
  }
  
 
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Friend alphonse = new Friend("Alphonse");
    Friend gaston = new Friend("Gaston");
    
  // for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
    new Thread(() -> alphonse.bow(gaston)).start();
           
    new Thread(() -> gaston.bow(alphonse)).start();
    }
  }
    
}
```

As it turned out 2, the code is quite suitable and it doesn't matter in what order the threads work, but the order of messages is important. But approach 2 is complicated by the fact that when the threads increase, we need a lot of synchronization objects. They said that you just need to change a couple of lines and everything will work. 3 code is the code of the task itself in its original form (so where you need to change the lines).
I understand that 2 threads work with different objects and therefore synchronized does not work as it should (we are blocking on bowBack, maybe it is worth rewriting it?)

```
package pr1;

import java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.Lock;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock;

//package ru.philosophyit;

public class DeadLock {

  static Object o = new Object();
  
  static class Friend {
    private final String name;
    
    
    public Friend(String name) {
      this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName() {
      return name;
    }
    
    public synchronized void bow(Friend bower) {
        
        {   
                 System.out.format("%s: %s подстрелил меня!\n", this.name, bower.getName());
                 System.out.format("%s: стреляю в ответ!\n", this.name);
                         
                 bower.bowBack(this);
    }
    }
             
    public synchronized void bowBack(Friend bower) 
    {
            {
        System.out.format("%s: %s подстрелил меня!\n", this.name, bower.getName());
    }
    }
  }
  
 
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Friend alphonse = new Friend("Alphonse");
    Friend gaston = new Friend("Gaston");
    
   for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
    new Thread(() -> alphonse.bow(gaston)).start();
           
    new Thread(() -> gaston.bow(alphonse)).start();
   
    
    }
  }
    
}
```

Comment: The language barrier is one thing, but it would be nice if you could post a MCVE and indicate the exact errors / situations that you are encountering. "everything collapses" and "we don't have what we need" are not all that helpful.

Comment: To avoid deadlocks you need to take locks on objects in the same order in all threads like first take lock on an object with smaller hashcode. Or you can use implementation of `Lock` interface and method `tryLock` with timeout

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow!
"if you call the threads, it will work, but if you call the threads into a loop, everything collapses". 
Could you edit your question to include the code where you call threads into a loop? This would help us distinguish the situations that work/don't work.

Comment: @Ivan i tried tryLock with timeout but the problem remains in the loop. If I run it, everything will go to sleep. Apparently I do not quite understand how to implement this correctly

Comment: Why are you starting 10 threads? You don't really have any flow control regarding who grabs the lock again when their free. Also note that your two lock loop, it is very likely that one thread will grab a lock, and then another thread will grab the other lock then they'll never break out of that loop. This has to do with the locking order.

Comment: @matt 10 threads I was trying to create a situation of increasing load to see if threads are blocked or not. I've tried 10 to 10,000 to make sure threads are blocking correctly, but might this be a bad way?

Comment: @matt 1 code with tryLock is bad, I saw a lock there. I was told that it is better not to rewrite the code too much. There should be 2 streams to output AAGGGA. The option with a queue is interesting, but you have to rewrite everything, does not quite meet the requirements of the task. Or I misunderstood you?

Comment: Yes, just spinning off threads is bad. You would use an executor service of some sort and submit tasks. The problem with locks, is they don't offer any order. All of the threads get to the lock and wait. When it is free, any one of the threads grab it. The way I have set it up, it says, task A is ready, then it says taskB is ready. I don't using a queue changes your code that much. I rewrote it because it was easier for me, but you just need to apply the concept.

Answer (score 0):

Can we think of the arrow as a resource?

```
import java.util.concurrent.*;


public class Bowmen implements Runnable{
    String name;
    Bowmen target;
    SynchronousQueue<Object> queue = new SynchronousQueue<>();
    public Bowmen(String name){
        this.name = name;
    }
    
    public void shoot(String name, Object o) throws InterruptedException{
        System.out.println(this.name + " : " + name + " shot me.");
        queue.put(o);
    }
    
    public void run(){
        try{
            Object o = queue.take();
            System.out.println(this.name + " : I will shoot " + target.name);
            target.shoot(name, o);
        } catch(InterruptedException e){
            //just finish.
        }
    }
    public void setTarget(Bowmen t){
        target = t;
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
        
        Bowmen a = new Bowmen("a");
        Bowmen b = new Bowmen("b");
        
        a.setTarget(b);
        b.setTarget(a);
        
        for(int i = 0; i<5; i++){
            new Thread(a).start();
            new Thread(b).start();
        }
        //all the threads are waiting because there is no resource to share yet.
        a.shoot( null, new Object() );
    }

}
```

This will produce output

> a : null shot me.
> a : I will shoot b
> b : a shot me.
> b : I will shoot a
> ...

It will end with "a : b shot me." but the program will not finish because there isn't a thread taking from the queue to let the last call to shoot finish.